# Equation of motion for a compressed spring

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, harmonic-oscillator, free-body-diagram, spring

I've solved the equation of motion for a spring-mass system, many times, and found that the resultant motion is simple harmonic, as expected. However, in all the derivations, I've considered extending the spring, and considering the right side to be positive, as is, in the cartesian coordinate system. I ran into some problems, while trying to solve this, for a spring that has been compressed instead.

[image]

In the image, replace $-x$ by $-s$

Here, I've taken the positive $x$ direction as $\hat{i}$. Since the spring has been compressed to the left, the restoring force must act towards the right. From Hooke's law, I have :

$$\vec{F}=-k\vec{x}$$

In our example, the displacement is basically final position $-$ initial position $=$ $-s\hat{i}-0\hat{i}=-s\hat{i}.$ Plugging this into my original equation I get :

$$\vec{F}=-k(-s)\hat{i}=ks\hat{i}$$

This is exactly what we would expect to see i.e. the force acting towards the right, towards positive $x$, in the $\hat{i}$ direction.

However now I try to solve the equation of motion. I can say, in the $x$ direction :

$$\sum F_x=ks=m\ddot{x}$$

This makes sense. If $s$ is large, that would imply the spring is more compressed, so the restoring force would produce a greater acceleration.

However, this is obviously incorrect, because this doesn't represent a harmonic oscillator. Instead I should have a negative sign in the above equation, to make it correct.

It has been suggested to me that since in this coordinate system, the displacement is negative, the acceleration must also be negative. This is essentially shown in this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/407718/317995). However I don't see why that should be the case. I can choose any direction to be positive, and write net force in that direction to be $ma$. Then I can find the resultant forces in that direction and equate both sides.

In this example, I've set the positive $x$ direction to be the direction where I want to find the net force. Then I've set the net force in this direction to be $ma$. The resultant force in this direction is $kx$. So I can set $ma=ks$. Solving this however doesn't yield the sinusoidal equation that I expect to see.

I could have also tried to find the resultant force in the negative $x$ direction. Net force in the negative $x$ direction is $ma$. Resultant force in the negative $x$ direction is $-ks$. Now I end up with the equation of motion $ma=-ks$.

However, just changing my coordinate axis shouldn't change my sum. Here, just by finding the net force in the positive and negative $x$ direction, I've obtained two different equations of motion.

Can anyone help clear my confusion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first off, I think you're using $ x $ for too many things. You're using it for a random vector in

$$ \vec{F} = - k \vec{x} ,$$

and for a positive parameter that denotes the position to where you compress the string. You're basically saying that $ \vec{x} = - x \hat{i} $, which I find a bit confusing.

Nevertheless, if you wish to use this notation, you have to be consistent, and when you write $ \vec{F} = m \ddot{\vec{x}} $, you need to take it in consideration. This will yield you

$$ \vec{F} = m \ddot{\vec{x}} = m \ddot{(- x \hat{i})} = - m \ddot{x} \hat{i}. $$

Equating this with $ \vec{F} = k x \hat{i} $ gives the correct answer,

$$ m \ddot{x} = - k x. $$

However, I advise you to define clearly each thing when you're formulating the problem. If you want to express your position in terms of a positive parameter, say that $ \vec{x} = - a \hat{i} $ for instance.

Be as it may, congratulations on your critical thinking initiative! I'm sure that keeping like this, you'll strive on any area!

Comment: @RayPalmer You changed the positive parameter x for s but I'll keep my answer like this so it considers the whole issue.

Comment: Ah I think I get what happened here. The biggest issue it seems was naming everything as $x$, as the previous answer mentions. What I initially wrote was $m\ddot{x}=kx$, but in this equation the two $x$ meant different things. On the LHS, $x$ was the distance along whichever direction I chose to be positive. On the RHS however, $x$ was the magnitude of the displacement. So, if I label the magnitude of the displacement as $s$, then the equation reads $m\ddot{x}=ks$. Now I need to write it in terms of $s$, and I'd get the correct answer. Thank you so much for this.

Answer (score 2):

You've used $x$ to mean two different things: the distance toward the right relative to the origin (as in the $x$-axis marked in your figure) and the *magnitude* of the distance from the origin (as in your equation $\vec{F}=-k(-x)\hat{i}=kx\hat{i}$). The second is bad practice and is why you identify a contradiction for $x<0$. Instead, considering denoting $|x|$ as $d$ or $s$ or something else.

These problems are very common when first working with free-body diagrams and equations of motion; the new practitioner feels a need to "correct" for negative values. But that correction is already built into $\vec{F}=-k\vec{x}$; the restoring force always points in the opposite direction of the displacement.

Comment: I've replaced that by using $s$ to denote the magnitude of the distance. However, I'm still not able to see how this solves my problem. I'm ending up with $m\ddot{x}=ks$, where I should have something like $m\ddot{s}=-ks$. Can you elaborate on that please ?

Comment: If you choose to start using absolute differences, then your equation of motion will be piecewise defined: $m\ddot{x}=ks$ when $x<0$ and $m\ddot{x}=-ks$ when $x\ge 0$. There's really no need to introduce this complexity when working with springs, but it does become necessary when working with [Coulomb friction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/676109/what-is-the-equation-of-motion-for-a-harmonic-motion-damped-by-constant-friction).